# How to display a $ next to a number in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, string, numbers, concatenation

this is what I am trying, but the '$' doesn't get displayed in the result set

```
SELECT
  id,
  CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name),
  CONCAT('$' + '' + salary),
  started_on
FROM employees
WHERE salary >= 100000 AND started_on >= '20180101'
ORDER BY salary DESC, id;
```

Comment: In MySQL `+` has strictly numeric context. So `$` and `' '` are converted to a number which has zero value.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do it in SQL:

```
CONCAT('$', salary)
```

You really should do it in the presentation layer (your app).

Comment: There could be a case that the app is `mysql` or  ... INTO OUTFILE.

Comment: @Hendrik. It could be. In general it is good to separate the presentation from the data queries.